# How to translate url encoded string python

Tags: python

This code is supposed to download a list of pdfs into a directory

```
for pdf in preTag:
    pdfUrl = "https://the-eye.eu/public/Books/Programming/" + 
    pdf.get("href")
    print("Downloading...%s"% pdfUrl)
    #downloading pdf from url
    page = requests.get(pdfUrl)
    page.raise_for_status()

    #saving pdf to new directory
    pdfFile = open(os.path.join(filePath, os.path.basename(pdfUrl)), "wb")
    for chunk in page.iter_content(1000000):
        pdfFile.write(chunk)
pdfFile.close()
```

I used `os.path.basename()` just to make sure the files would actually download. However, I want to know how to change the file name from `3D%20Printing%20Blueprints%20%5BeBook%5D.pdf` to something like "3D Printing Blueprints.pdf"

Comment: Hello, i think you should edit your question. If you want an information about manipulating strings or changing the name of a file, we really do not need to know all your code. Please take one minute to read this : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [urllib2 unquote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) function:

```
import urllib2
print urllib2.unquote("3D%20Printing%20Blueprints%20%5BeBook%5D.pdf") #3D Printing Blueprints.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
os.rename("3D%20Printing%20Blueprints%20%5BeBook%5D.pdf", "3D Printing Blueprints.pdf")
```

you can find more info [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm)